# AX 2009: Can't find "SalesCreateReleaseOrderLineTmp" Table

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2009

I am a beginner in AX and I am trying to set access rights for some users and on a specific operation they get the error that they don't have access to the table `SalesCreateReleaseOrderLineTmp`. I have manually searched for this table in every category, but without success. I found on a website the full description of this table -> `Order Lines - SalesCreateReleaseOrderLineTmp - ID: 995`. I've search for the ID as well, but again no result. With admin rights everything is ok, but obviously not a solution.

Is there a fix location of this table and can anyone tell me where it is? :) Or is there any way to search for this table (by ID or name)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess with

> I have manually searched for this table in every category, but without
>   success

you mean you tried to find the table in the form for maintaining the user group permissions?
If so then this is due to the fact that temporary tables are hidden from that tree view as the class method `SysDictTable.allowSecuritySetup` is called from `SysSecurity.expandSecurityKey` while building the tree view and in this method there is - among other things - a check whether the table is temporary.

So essentially you have 3 options:

1. Give your permission group the desired access on the security key so that the group 'inherits' access to the table through it - downside of course could be to be too permissive but upside is better maintainability :)
2. Remove the security key on the temporary table as this in general is IMHO a wrong decision anyway. The application shouldn't restrict access to temporary tables (which are intrinsically scoped to the user session anyway) but rather force access checks in the code filling that table or even higher level processes.
3. Customize the code which builds the security tree view so that it includes temp. tables.

Try to apply the first option above that works for you as the first one does not need any application modification and the second one is only a simple property change which in my opinion is currently bad configured anyway. The last option should be the last resort.